# How do I get notifications from an asynchronous RIA Services call?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, asynchronous, notifications, wcf-ria-services

I've got an application set up with RIA Services, Entity Framework 4, and Silverlight 4.  It is set up in the fashion prescribed on MSDN here: [Walkthrough: Creating a RIA Services Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707376%28v=VS.91%29.aspx)

On the client side, this code loads the customer entities into a grid's ItemsSource:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        LoadOperation<Customer> loadOp = this._customerContext.Load(this._customerContext.GetCustomersQuery());
        CustomerGrid.ItemsSource = loadOp.Entities;
    }
```

The call to "loadOp.Entities" is done asynchronously (automatically by RIA Services).  How do I get notification when the asynchronous call is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a callback.  I haven't used the official release of RIA yet, but in the beta it was used like so.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    LoadOperation<Customer> loadOp = this._customerContext.Load(this._customerContext.GetCustomersQuery(),MyCallback,null);
    CustomerGrid.ItemsSource = loadOp.Entities;
}

private void MyCallback(LoadOperation<Customer> loadOperation)
{
    //This will be called when the load is complete
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.  There is an additional argument requireed for Load in the released version of RIA Services, e.g.  this._customerContext.Load(this._customerContext.GetCustomersQuery(),MyCallback, null);

Comment: Yeah I forgot the `objectState` argument.  That's a pretty standard argument on async calls in all of .NET.